# Hover underline effect with Elementor CSS

Tags: css, elementor

I have been hitting my head against a brickwall with this issue.
I have tried using this line of code to create an underline on hover effect with CSS using Elementor. I've tried it with a button widget and a Text Editor widget but can't seem to get it to work at all. What am I missing?
Any help would be really helpful.

Thanks

```
:
.underline {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.underline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #000;
  height: 4px;
  transition-property: left right;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.underline:hover:after,
.underline:focus:after,
.underline:active:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: That said don't transition left or right, transition the width from 100% to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works - the problem is the transition-property. You have left right which is not legal CSS. And in fact you only want to transition the right property, the underline stays anchored at the left side.

```css
.underline {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.underline::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: #000;
  height: 4px;
  transition-property: right;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.underline:hover::after,
.underline:focus:after,
.underline:active:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="underline">Hover over me</div>
```

It can be helpful to run your code through the relvant validator. In this case I used the W3C CSS validator which picked up the error.

Although you can transition (animate) the right property as you have done it is often more performant (in CPU/GPU usage sense) to use transforms such as scale or translate to shrink/grow or move things.